# Salesforce Napili Lightning Community - how to get rid of URL parameters

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, url, napili, parameters

Is there a way in a Lightning Component to tell it to remove the parameters from the current URL? If I add parameters at some point during navigation, Salesforce keeps those parameters through the whole session, even when the user navigates to multiple other pages. This is messing up how I want some pages to work.

Comment: I have used parameter passing but it messed other thing.  Can I ask why are you passing parameters? I belive most can be done without passing parameters.

Comment: I have a search/filter feature where if someone clicks on a result and then clicks on a back button I made, the search/filter settings are preserved. They don't want them preserved forever though. Basically, I'm using it to communicate between pages.

Comment: looks like bad architecture, I wonder if you could use cookies isntead